# How to pass a variable from view to controller using javascript on change in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I want to passing a variable (id) from view to controller using javascript onChange. I have done it but the result when I'm do `dd` always the same. In my case i always get "7".

Here is my code:

**View**:

```
 <select id="jurusan_id" type="text" name="jurusan_id" onchange="filterJurusan()">
       <option value disable>Jurusan</option>
         @foreach (App\Models\Admin\Jurusan::all() as $jurusan)
          <option value="{{ $jurusan->id }}">{{ $jurusan->nama_jurusan }}</option>
         @endforeach
    </select>
```

**Route**:

```
 Route::get('datasiswa/{id}', 'Admin\SiswaController@filterSiswa')->name('filterSiswa');
```

**Js:**

```
function filterJurusan() {
  window.location.href = "{{ route('filterSiswa', $jurusan->id) }}";
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function filterSiswa(Request $request, $id)
  {
      dd($id);
  }
```

I know something was wrong with my code, but i can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing server-side and client-side code. The JS code piece renders the route once upon loading. The `$jurusan` variable is set to the last object of your foreach loop. Therefore the `id` will always be 7.

You will have to get the selected item. For that adjust the onchange function:

```
onchange="filterJurusan(this)"
```

Afterwards you can get the value, which is the id like this.

```
function filterJurusan(el) {
 var value = (el.value || el.options[el.selectedIndex].value); 
  window.location.href = '/datasiswa/'+value;
}
```

Now the question is if you simply want to change the location (like in the code) or as your function names indicate, want to filter data?

Comment: I want to filter data using select. So i need an id as a parameter. Btw this code working

Comment: if you want to stay on the same page you will have to make some ajax requests :)

Comment: Thanks for information, then I'll do some research about using ajax for filtering data

Comment: @Catto I don't know much you want to learn (or read about) but a good choice would be to use Vue.js (this will make displaying dynamic data very easy)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are populating Jurusan records on view by `App\Models\Admin\Jurusan::all() as $jurusan`. What this does is populate options in your select but at the end of iterations last record's data left stored in $jurusan variable that you are using in `function filterJurusan()` to call controller method. You should get `jurusanId = document.getElementById('jurusan_id')` and pass it to the controller like `window.location.href = '/datasiswa/' + jurusanId;`

Comment: You should return all records from the controller method using for this view. That's how you will achieve actual MVC.

Answer (score 0):

This can be more easier and accurate to get your result..

```
<form action="{{route('filterSiswa')}}" method="GET">
 <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="jurusan_id">
   <option value disable>Jurusan</option>
     @foreach (App\Models\Admin\Jurusan::all() as $jurusan)
      <option value="{{ $jurusan->id }}">{{ $jurusan->nama_jurusan }}</option>
     @endforeach
 </select>
 </form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but using this method i can't get id from foreach

Comment: Oh yes, I forget to mention that, you have to update your route,
Route::get('datasiswa', 'Admin\SiswaController@filterSiswa')->name('filterSiswa'); 

And catch id in controller  as  follow:
request()->id